# How to get "text-embedding-ada-002"?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, embedding

I can get this model only with openai api-key?
I can get full vocabulary of token embeddings?
I can download this model or no?

I cant get information for this in different sources for a long time.

Sorry, my English is bad...

Comment: https://openai.com/blog/new-and-improved-embedding-model

Comment: This source does not have the information I need.

Comment: This is not really a programming problem, and if the model is available online behind an API, there is no guarantee that there will be a website or document stating this explicitly. OpenAI is being very closed now, so you have to read between the lines.

Comment: When you ask how to get it, are you asking how you can use it, or are you asking how to download the model locally? The second one is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's asking how to run this locally. To the best of my knowledge, this model is only available via the OpenAI service, ie behind their API.